# No logro hacer funcionar loader de sass en webpack 5

Tags: webpack, sass

Estoy usando esta config de webpack de este repo https://github.com/santiagoOjeda/react-boilerplate.git, en el branch enhancement/sass-loader

Alguna idea de que esta mal, me da el siguiente msj:

RROR in ./src/pages/home/styles.scss 1:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> $font-size: 1rem;
> | $font-color: lch(53 105 40);
> |
> @ ./src/index.js 4:0-34

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // aca deberia ir una variable de entorno
  //mode: "development",
  // archivos de entrada
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // donde guardara los archivos del bundle y su config
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    // resuelve las extensiones de los archivos nombrados, no hace falta escribirlas
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      // CSS, PostCSS, and Sass
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  // config del server local
  devServer: {
    port: 4000,
  },
  // plugins, para poder enteders por ej: html
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```